# How to load Notes for Projects in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have notes in my Pipedrive tool for each deals. Now i need to migrate those notes for each deal in Pipedrive to my Salesforce. How can I get the notes for each project loaded to its corresponding project. I try loading notes by giving project ID through Data Loader Wizard. Even-though the tool says that the data is loaded successfully, When I go to my Project in Salesforce, I am not able to see the Notes for the project.

Please help.

Thanks

Niki

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Projects'? I don't get the point. Is it a custom object or what?

Comment: In my case it is Opportunities what I consider as Project.